# Specifying Windows service dependencies in app.config?

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation, dependencies

I'm creating a Windows service which will depend on the SQL Server service having started up before mine.  I know you can add such a dependency from code, the Windows GUI, or the command line via `sc`, but is it possible to specify such dependencies in the service's `app.config`?  Are there any other ways to setup service dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the app.config is concerned, there is nothing you can put in there that will delay the starting of your service until after another service is running.  You have to do this at the OS level ([`sc`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sc.mspx?mfr=true) or [registry](http://www.boyce.us/windows/servertipcontent.asp?ID=7)), not at the service level (app.config).

In general, though, writing your service with the expectation that another service is running makes your service fragile.  What if the local system admin deletes SQL Server from the machine or configures it not to run by default?  In either of these two cases, your service will ***never*** run.

Instead, I would suggest that you write your service in such a way that it does not depend on another service to start, even if it requires that service in order to do any work.  For example, if your service queries the database based on a remote user request and SQL Server is not running at that time, throw an exception that can then be displayed to the user.

Alternatively, when you install your service, add the dependency on SQL Server at that point *if* you can reasonably expect SQL Server to be there.

Comment: davis The service is supposed to immediately start up and poll the DB, rather than connect in response to something.  How would you write that without adding a dependency on SQL Server?

Comment: Please don't misunderstand.  There's nothing wrong with adding a dependency, but relying on that dependency alone is not robust enough because there's always the possibility that SQL Server may not start due to unforeseen circumstances.  In that case, I would assume you still want your service to run.  If your service polls from the start, just add the appropriate exception handling.  If an exception occurs, wait some period of time before polling again.  I would recommend doing this anyway *even if* you add a dependency on SQL Server.

Comment: Not a problem on the nickname.  I knew you who meant.  :)